# How to select two consecutive adjacent month?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I need help regarding a use case of selecting two previous/next consecutive adjacent months considering months are enabled for selection.

Use case 1:

```js
MONTH_LIST = [
  { id: '0', month: 'Apr', disabled: false },
  { id: '1', month: 'May', disabled: false },
  { id: '2', month: 'Jun', disabled: false },
  { id: '3', month: 'Jul', disabled: false },
  { id: '4', month: 'Aug', disabled: false },
  { id: '5', month: 'Sep', disabled: false },
  { id: '6', month: 'Oct', disabled: false },
  { id: '7', month: 'Nov', disabled: false },
  { id: '8', month: 'Dec', disabled: false },
  { id: '9', month: 'Jan', disabled: false },
  { id: '10', month: 'Feb', disabled: false },
  { id: '11', month: 'Mar', disabled: false },
];
Selected Year = 2021
Enabled Months = [
  { id: '0', month: 'Apr', disabled: false },
  { id: '1', month: 'May', disabled: false },
  { id: '2', month: 'Jun', disabled: false },
  { id: '3', month: 'Jul', disabled: false },
  { id: '4', month: 'Aug', disabled: false },
  { id: '5', month: 'Sep', disabled: true },
  { id: '6', month: 'Oct', disabled: true },
  { id: '7', month: 'Nov', disabled: true },
  { id: '8', month: 'Dec', disabled: true },
  { id: '9', month: 'Jan', disabled: true },
  { id: '10', month: 'Feb', disabled: true },
  { id: '11', month: 'Mar', disabled: true },
]
```

Now the user can select only the enabled months but wherever they start, they can select forward two months or the previous 2 months if available for selection.

For Example:
If he/she selects **Jun** then the next selection will be **July and Aug** or **May and Apr**

**Total Months to be selected = 3**

Also if the selected year is less than a current year then all 12 months will be available for selection but the same approach will be followed.

For Reference [Git Repo Link](https://github.com/papuruth/monthtest)
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7pm4c58/1/)

Comment: it would be better if you had code that was valid :)   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder

Comment: @denov code looks fine

Comment: "Enabled Months"  you can't have spaces in var names

Comment: @denov that's just an example. You can follow this https://jsfiddle.net/d7pm4c58/1/ for actual implementation